# Subclassed UIButton to make a circle, end up with a rectangle

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have the following class named PushButtonView.  It subclasses `UIButton`

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class PushButtonView: UIButton {
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
@IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()
@IBInspectable var isAddButton: Bool = true
@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()
@IBInspectable var useBorder: Bool = false
@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
    fillColor.setFill()

    //Path's don't draw anything. To draw the path, fill it.
    path.fill()

    //Set up width and height variables for the plus
    let plusHeight: CGFloat = 3.0
    let plusWidth: CGFloat = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) * 0.6

    //Create the path
    var plusPath = UIBezierPath()

    //Set the path's line width to the height of the stroke
    plusPath.lineWidth = plusHeight

    //Move the initial point of the path to the start of the horizontal stroke.
    //Point is the middle of the button - half of the width of the plus.
    plusPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2 - plusWidth/2 + 0.5, y: bounds.height/2 + 0.5))

    //Add a point to the path at the end of the stroke.
    //Final point is the middle of the button + half of the width of the plus.
    plusPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2 + plusWidth/2 + 0.5, y: bounds.height/2 + 0.5))

    if isAddButton {
        //Move the initial point of the path to the start of the vertical stroke.
        //Point is the middle of the button.  Start point is half of the height - half of the width of the plus.
        plusPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2 + 0.5, y: bounds.height/2 - plusWidth/2 + 0.5))

        //Add a point to the path at the end of the stroke.
        //Final point is the middle of the button.  Start pointis half of the heigh + half of the width of the plus
        plusPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2 + 0.5, y: bounds.height/2 + plusWidth/2 + 0.5))
    }

    //Set the stroke color
    UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke()

    //Stroke the path
    plusPath.stroke()

    if useBorder {
        //Extra code here.  Paints a black border around the button.  In order for it to be round, the
        //button width and height must be the same.  The cornerRadius must be half of the width (or height).
        super.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
        super.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        super.layer.cornerRadius = super.frame.width / 2 + 0.5
    }
}
}
```

Originally, I was using this to create buttons on a view.  I would drop an `UIBUtton` on the view and then set the class to PushButtonView.  As long as the width and height of the button are the same size, the button would take on the shape of a circle.

Now I am trying to use this class by creating buttons in code.  When I do this, I end up with a square button, instead of a round button.  Here's the code for creating the button.

```
    button1 = PushButtonView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)
    button1.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width/2, label.center.y - (label.frame.height/2) - 50)
    button1.fillColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button1.addTarget(self, action: "button1Clicked", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button1)
```

When I run it, the button is not a circle; it's a square.

If I drop a UIButton directly on the view and set the class to PushButtonView, then I end up with a round button.

Where am I going wrong with the code to create the button programmatically?

Comment: Did you just copy and paste the code from somewhere? It seems like you are using it but you don't understand it.

Comment: I think it's (at least partially) copied from here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/90690/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-1

Comment: I got the code online, and added some modifications to it.  Border and border color.  And per the answer below, I just messed up a line of code.  Thanks for the answer, Aaron Brager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to set `useBorder`:

```
button1.useBorder = true
```

Otherwise the layer's `cornerRadius` doesn't get set.

If this is correct, in the future, this is probably easier to debug by setting a breakpoint in `drawRect` and stepping through your implementation.